# xPath select finds several elements instead of one (sibling vs. following-sibling)

Tags: xpath

If I use the following xPath:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'some-label') and contains(., 'MT:Week')]
```

It gets me exactly **one** element (a `<span>`) as expected. So far so good.

What I want is to get the `<select>` right next to it, but by doing this:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'some-label') and contains(., 'MT:Week')]/following::select
```

It already selects **two** `<select>` elements. How do I select just one  **without using the name attribute (!)** ?

The HTML:

```
<div>
  <label>
    <span class="some-label">MT:Month</span>
    <select name="month" id="someID">
      <option selected="selected" value="12">March 2015</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>

<div>
  <label>
    <span class="some-label">MT:Week</span>
<!-- want to select just the below one -->
    <select class="width-50px" name="monthWeek" id="someOtherID"> 
      <option selected="selected" value="">All</option>
      <option value="CalendarWeek{year=2015, week=9}">9</option>
      <option value="CalendarWeek{year=2015, week=10}">10</option>

    </select>
  </label>
</div>


<div>
  <label>
    <span class="some-label">MT:Type</span>
    <select name="type" id="anotherID">
      <option selected="selected" value="">All</option>
      <option value="someValue">Value 1</option>
      <option value="someValue2">Value 2</option>

    </select>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [1] to get the first:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'some-label') and contains(., 'MT:Week')]/following::select[1]
```

But you probably only want the one within the same label, so use **following-sibling**:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'some-label') and contains(., 'MT:Week')]/following-sibling::select
```

Comment: It is surprising that we have written the same two expression with a difference of 5 seconds :)

Comment: @BeniBela. Thanks, it wokrs. Now learned the difference between sibling vs. following-sibling. Good sources with examples are here -- http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example15.html and http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example17.html

Comment: @splash58 It seems to happen almost every time